# Understanding why results between Keras and Tensorflow are different

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently trying to do some work in both Keras and Tensorflow, I stumbled upon a small thing I do not understand. If you look at the code below, I am trying to predict the responses of a network either via Tensorflow session explicitly, or by using the model predict_on_batch function.

```
import os
import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Input
from keras.models import Model

# Try to standardize output
np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)

# Building the model
inputs = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
base_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet', \
                                    input_tensor=inputs, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = base_model.get_layer("fc2").output
x = Dropout(0.5, name='model_fc_dropout')(x)
x = Dense(2048, activation='sigmoid', name='final_fc')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5, name='final_fc_dropout')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='fcout')(x)
model = Model(outputs=predictions, inputs=inputs)

##################################################################
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=5e-4, momentum=0.9),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

image_batch = np.random.random((64,224,224,3))

# Outputs predicted by TF
outs = [predictions]
feed_dict={inputs:image_batch,  K.learning_phase():0}

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    outputs = sess.run(outs, feed_dict)[0]
    print outputs.flatten()

# Outputs predicted by Keras
outputs = model.predict_on_batch(image_batch)
print outputs.flatten()
```

My issue is that I got two different results, even though I tried to remove any kind of sources of randomness by setting the seeds to 1 and running the operations on CPU. Even then, I get the following results:

```
[ 0.26079229  0.26078743  0.26079154  0.26079673  0.26078942  0.26079443
  0.26078886  0.26079088  0.26078972  0.26078728  0.26079121  0.26079452
  0.26078513  0.26078424  0.26079014  0.26079312  0.26079521  0.26078743
  0.26078558  0.26078537  0.26078674  0.26079136  0.26078632  0.26077667
  0.26079312  0.26078999  0.26079065  0.26078704  0.26078928  0.26078624
  0.26078892  0.26079202  0.26079065  0.26078689  0.26078963  0.26078749
  0.26078817  0.2607986   0.26078528  0.26078412  0.26079187  0.26079246
  0.26079226  0.26078457  0.26078099  0.26078072  0.26078376  0.26078475
  0.26078326  0.26079389  0.26079792  0.26078579  0.2607882   0.2607961
  0.26079237  0.26078218  0.26078638  0.26079753  0.2607787   0.26078618
  0.26078096  0.26078594  0.26078215  0.26079002]
```

and

```
[ 0.25331706  0.25228402  0.2534174   0.25033095  0.24851511  0.25099936
  0.25240892  0.25139931  0.24948661  0.25183493  0.25104815  0.25164133
  0.25214729  0.25265765  0.25128496  0.25249782  0.25247478  0.25314394
  0.25014618  0.25280923  0.2526398   0.25381723  0.25138992  0.25072744
  0.25069866  0.25307226  0.25063521  0.25133523  0.25050756  0.2536433
  0.25164688  0.25054023  0.25117773  0.25352773  0.25157067  0.25173825
  0.25234801  0.25182116  0.25284401  0.25297374  0.25079012  0.25146705
  0.25401884  0.25111189  0.25192681  0.25252578  0.25039044  0.2525287
  0.25165257  0.25357804  0.25001243  0.2495154   0.2531895   0.25270832
  0.25305843  0.25064403  0.25180396  0.25231308  0.25224048  0.25068772
  0.25212681  0.24812476  0.25027585  0.25243458]
```

Does anybody have an idea what could be going on in the background that could change the results? (These results do not change if one runs them again)

The difference gets even bigger if the network runs on a GPU (Titan X), e.g. the second output is:

```
[ 0.3302682   0.33054096  0.32677746  0.32830611  0.32972822  0.32807562
  0.32850873  0.33161065  0.33009702  0.32811245  0.3285495   0.32966742
  0.33050382  0.33156893  0.3300975   0.3298254   0.33350074  0.32991216
  0.32990077  0.33203539  0.32692945  0.33036903  0.33102706  0.32648
  0.32933888  0.33161271  0.32976636  0.33252293  0.32859167  0.33013415
  0.33080408  0.33102706  0.32994759  0.33150592  0.32881773  0.33048317
  0.33040857  0.32924038  0.32986534  0.33131596  0.3282761   0.3292698
  0.32879189  0.33186096  0.32862625  0.33067161  0.329018    0.33022234
  0.32904804  0.32891914  0.33122411  0.32900628  0.33088413  0.32931429
  0.3268061   0.32924181  0.32940546  0.32860965  0.32828435  0.3310211
  0.33098024  0.32997403  0.33025959  0.33133432]
```

whereas in the first one, the differences only occur in the 5th and latter decimal places:

```
[ 0.26075357  0.26074868  0.26074538  0.26075155  0.260755    0.26073951
  0.26074919  0.26073971  0.26074231  0.26075247  0.2607362   0.26075858
  0.26074955  0.26074123  0.26074299  0.26074946  0.26074076  0.26075014
  0.26074076  0.26075229  0.26075041  0.26074776  0.26075897  0.26073995
  0.260746    0.26074466  0.26073912  0.26075709  0.26075712  0.26073799
  0.2607322   0.26075566  0.26075059  0.26073873  0.26074558  0.26074558
  0.26074359  0.26073721  0.26074392  0.26074731  0.26074862  0.26074174
  0.26074126  0.26074588  0.26073804  0.26074919  0.26074269  0.26074606
  0.26075307  0.2607446   0.26074025  0.26074648  0.26074952  0.26073608
  0.26073566  0.26073873  0.26074576  0.26074475  0.26074636  0.26073411
  0.2607542   0.26074755  0.2607449   0.2607407 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here results are different as `initializations` are different.

Tf uses the this `init_op` for variables initializations.

```
sess.run(init_op)
```

But Keras uses its own `init_op` inside its model class, not the `init_op` defined in your codes.